# angular-moment is not loaded by angular in meteor app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-meteor, angular-moment

I do tutorial from angular-meteor.com. angular-moment worked well. Then I added some Ionic elements to html page and empty stub method to controller. And got the message:

> 13:07:29.038 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   Whatsapp due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   angular-moment due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-moment' is
>   not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load
>   it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies
>   as the second argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=angular-moment
>   minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=a65f000925e20c56ee4ab84205897b99db3e2c9f:232:12
>   module/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=a65f000925e20c56ee4ab84205897b99db3e2c9f:2198:1
>   ensure@http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=a65f000925e20c56ee4ab84205897b99db3e2c9f:2122:38
>   module@http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=a65f000925e20c56ee4ab84205897b99db3e2c9f:2196:1
>   loadModules/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=a65f000925e20c56ee4ab84205897b99db3e2c9f:4688:22
>   forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?has minErr/<()
>   modules.js:232 loadModules/<() modules.js:4711 forEach()
>   modules.js:485 loadModules() modules.js:4672 createInjector()
>   modules.js:4594 bootstrap/doBootstrap() modules.js:1874 bootstrap()
>   modules.js:1895 onReady() app.js:100
>   require<.node_modules.meteor.jquery["jquery.js"]/

I rolled back my changes, by commenting them out, but still have this error.

UPDATE
The following code causes error:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-meteor';
import 'angular-moment';
import 'angular-sanitize';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import 'ionic-scripts';

// Modules
import Definer from '../definer';
import ChatsCtrl from '../controllers/chats.controller';
import ChatCtrl from '../controllers/chat.controller';
import CalendarFilter from '../filters/calendar.filter';
import RoutesConfig from '../routes';

// App
const App = angular.module('Whatsapp', [
    'angular-meteor',
```

> ```
>   'angular-moment',
> ```

```
    'ionic'
]);
```

Module angular-moment was installed as follows:

```
>meteor npm install --save angular-moment
angular-moment@1.0.0-beta.5 node_modules/angular-moment
└── moment@2.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Clever... Documentation says it must be named angularMoment.. Very nice.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);
```

There is a mistake in tutorial. As for me, naming module in such a way makes coding more error-prone, because import is makes for angular-moment, but anlike others modules, it name is another.